# Cannot cast from Chromecast to javascriptexecutor (Selenium Javascript training)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting the error cannot cast from Chromecast to javascriptexecutor. Selenium version is 4.10.0

Here is the entire code:

```
package UI;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;

public class JavascriptExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\browserdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://ebay.co.uk");
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        JavascriptExecutor jxect = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

Answer (score 1):

That happened because you named class as `JavascriptExecutor`.
So, Java doesn't search for interface of `JavascriptExecutor` from Selenium and tries to cast driver instance to your current class (and, for sure, that is illegal type cast).

To resolve this issue, try to rename your current class to another name, for example, `JavascriptExecutorTest`.

Comment: I just right clicked, I didnt see "Rename" , whats the option to rename, please?

Comment: Usually it's Shift+F6 in IDE

Comment: RIght click >> Refractor > Rename.